# mplayer -ao pcm:file=C:\x.wav

Tags: windows, path, mplayer

Not sure where this should be posted...

Anyway, if i run the following command in a windows XP console it gives me a weird error and i have no ideea why.

```
mplayer "1.mp3" -vc "null" -vo "null" -ao "pcm:file=C:\1.wav"

Could not parse arguments at the position indicated below:
file=C:\1.wav
       ^
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pcm:file=C:\1.wav'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
```

I have never encountered such an error, and it seems to dislike the X:\ drive notation

Answer (score 2):

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2009-January/075711.html

Seems that 
    mplayer "1.mp3" -vc "null" -vo "null" -ao pcm:file=\"C:\1.wav\"
does the trick:D

Comment: 23 seconds before me :-)

Comment: But mine was wrong anyway, the key point: ``Make sure you quote it in a way so that your shell/command line will not
remove the " but passes them to MPlayer.''